# How to move the overall caption of a figure to use the available space?

Tags: captions, subcaption

I would like to move a figure caption to utilize the space better in my document. Here is some example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{one}
            \label{one}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{one}
            \label{two}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{one}
            \label{three}
        \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{four}
        \label{four}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{fice}
        \label{five}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{six}
        \label{six}
    \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{seven}
    \label{seven}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{I am a long overall caption but to save space in my paper I would like to put me in the extra space within the figure. I am a long overall caption but to save space in my paper I would like to put me in the extra space within the figure. I am a long overall caption but to save space in my paper I would like to put me in the extra space within the figure. }
    \label{}
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:
[image]

How would I make this figure look something like this (which I made with paint).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manually you can do it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{one}
            \label{one}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{one}
            \label{two}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{one}
            \label{three}
        \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{four}
        \label{four}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{fice}
        \label{five}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{six}
        \label{six}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{seven}
    \label{seven}
    \end{subfigure}

    \vspace{-7\baselineskip}\captionsetup{margin={0.30\linewidth,0pt}}
    \caption{I am a long overall caption but to save space in my paper I would like to put me in the extra space within the figure. I am a long overall caption but to save space in my paper I would like to put me in the extra space within the figure. I am a long overall caption but to save space in my paper I would like to put me in the extra space within the figure. }
    \label{}
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. In my own code I'm having difficulty tuning the location of the caption in the horizontal plane. I'm changing the margin size which when 0.6 the caption is on the far right and when 0.4 the caption is on the far left. Do you have any advice?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Better show the code. (You did see that the margin key has two values for the left and the right?).

Comment: Ah yes, got it. I thought the second argument was for text size (the `pt` bit). Perhaps showing my latex nativity there. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Since you want three figures each 25% of the text width, the space between them is 12.5% of the text width. Then we can create a `tabular` with `\tabcolsep` set at `0.0625\textwidth`. The last two columns will thus occupy 25%+12.5%+25%=62.5% of the text width.

Setting the `subfigure` environments to have top alignment and with a zero space at the top we achieve alignment to the top of the images. Then a `\multicolumn{2}{p{0.625\textwidth}@{}}{\caption{...}}` will solve the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.0625\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{} c c c @{}}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\linewidth}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{one}
  \label{one}
\end{subfigure}
&
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\linewidth}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{one}
  \label{two}
\end{subfigure}
&
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\linewidth}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{one}
  \label{three}
\end{subfigure}
\\
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\linewidth}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{four}
  \label{four}
\end{subfigure}
&
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\linewidth}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{five}
  \label{five}
\end{subfigure}
&
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\linewidth}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{six}
  \label{six}
\end{subfigure}
\\
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\linewidth}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{seven}
  \label{seven}
  \end{subfigure}
&
\multicolumn{2}{p{0.625\textwidth}@{}}{%
  \caption{I am a long overall caption but to save space 
    in my paper I would like to put me in the extra space
    within the figure. I am a long overall caption but to
    save space in my paper I would like to put me in the
    extra space within the figure. I am a long overall
    caption but to save space in my paper I would like to
    put me in the extra space within the figure.}
  \label{full}}
\end{tabular}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]